# Android menuItem Listener?

Tags: android, android-menu

When you create a button, you can assign a listener to capture user actions like clicks.

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //do some stuff
        }
    });

}
```

My question is why menu items don't need a listener? All I need is just write
`getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`

inside of

`public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`.

and use

`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

to define behaviour when an Item is clicked. I didn't see any setListener method. Besides, the main activity class does not implement any Listener. How does a menuItem work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does a menuItem work?

So `OptionsMenu` is build-in widget in Android `OS`

It works simply said like when you'll click on an item then is immediately called `"OnItemSelectedListener"` (you don't need to implement it, it's automatic called whenever you'll click on the item). This listener is already implemented. You don't have to implement it and i think you shouldn't and can't.

An `onOptionsItemSelected` method is called by listener that is called when you'll click on the item.

---

And what docs exactly say:

> This hook is called whenever an item in your options menu is selected.
>   The default implementation simply returns false to have the normal
>   processing happen (calling the item's Runnable or sending a message to
>   its Handler as appropriate). You can use this method for any items for
>   which you would like to do processing without those other facilities.
>
> Derived classes should call through to the base class for it to
>   perform the default menu handling.

Comment: oh ic. Is there any other build-in widgets that do not need listener?

Comment: @Timtianyang `ContextMenu` for example.